# ListView with Strings: Cannot get it to update the text of a button

Tags: android, kotlin, listview

So I'm wanting to create a ListView of buttons in Kotlin. When the view is created, it makes an API request and gets the names of the devices registered to the account and puts it into an array of strings called `deviceNames`.

Below is my code for trying to get the button to work. I used the tutorial that is found [here](https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin-android/kotlin-android-listview-example/), but when I try to compile it I get an error that the `ArrayAdapter` function doesn't have an input with the types that they gave. I have a button with the id of `deviceButton` in the view, but it can't find it for some reason.

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.deviceButton, deviceNames)
val listView: ListView = findViewById(R.id.deviceList)
listView.setAdapter(adapter)
```

The declaration of `deviceNames` is below. Inside of the for loop, the JSON array that was received from the API request is separated into its different objects and the property `name` is put into the `deviceNames` array.

```
var deviceNames = Array<String>(6) {""}

for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
     val device = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
     deviceNames[i] = device.get("name") as String
     println(deviceNames[I])
}
```

Sorry if this is a simple problem, I'm really new to Kotlin and Android.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the declaration/initialization of `deviceNames`

Comment: @avalerio I just added it, sory for the delayed response